# passing value to another activity in ontouch listener

Tags: android

I have an array of web view. I am implementing a touch event in web view. My requirement is that I want to pass the value to another activity in ontouch listener.

Can anybody give an example?

```
for(int i=0;i<articleParsedValue.size();i++)
        {
                ArticleDataSet articleDataset=(ArticleDataSet)articleParsedValue.get(i);
                HashMap<String, String> mapValue=new HashMap<String, String>();  

            WebView webviewcontent=new WebView(this);
           String html ="<html><body><div><label style=\"font:bold 17.5px verdana; color:#C1002B\">"+articleDataset.getArticle_title()+"<label style=\"font:13px verdana; color:#000000\">"+"|"+"</label>"+"<label style=\"font:bold 13px verdana; color:#000000\">"+articleDataset.getArticle_type()+"</label><br><label style=\"font:13px verdana; color:#AAAAAA\">"+articleDataset.getArticle_date()+" </label> </div>";
           html=html+"<div><label style=\"font:13px verdana; color:#000000\">"+articleDataset.getArticle_summary()+"</label></div></body></html>" ;
           webviewcontent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           webviewcontent.clearCache(true);
           webviewcontent.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
           webviewcontent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                      {

                        //@Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Intent newIntent=new Intent(this,MyCompaniesActivity.class);
                            newIntent.putExtra("articleid", articleDataset.getArticle_id()); 
                            startActivity(newIntent);
                            return false;
                        }




           }

        ) ;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you can pass the values to other Activity using **Bundle** class as shown below.

```
    Intent in = new Intent(BS_Bars.this, Ads.class);
    Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
    b1.putString("img_key", VALUE_ADS[0]);
    in.putExtras(b1);
    startActivity(in);
```

and you can retrieve these values in the destination activity as shown below.

```
  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
  String url = b.getString("img_key");
```